# Remove outer padding in tikzcd

Tags: tikz-cd

This is the result I would like to obtain using tikz-cd

```
A = \ker \left(B \xrightarrow{F} C\right)
```

but

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\[
  A = \ker \left(
  \begin{tikzcd}
    A \rar["F"] & B
  \end{tikzcd}
  \right)
\]
\end{document}
```

gives me too much spacing.

Is there an option to remove the extra padding?

Comment: While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

This is especially important for `tikz` as there are numerous libraries.

Comment: Try the `\begin{tikzcd}[cramped]` option and `sep=small` will reduce the spacing between the paren

Comment: The cramped option did exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the `cramped, sep=small` options to `tikzcd` you can obtain the desired spacing

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[
    A = \ker \left(B \xrightarrow{F} C\right)
\]
\[
    A = \ker \left(
    \begin{tikzcd}[cramped, sep=small] 
      A \rar["F"] & B
    \end{tikzcd}
    \right)
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Upvoted, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

If you deem that `\xrightarrow` produces too short an arrow, you can patch it in order to use a minimum width (here `2.5em`).

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\ext@arrow}
  {\hbox to\wd\tw@}
  {\hbox to\maybe@wd\tw@}
  {}{\ddt}
\newcommand{\maybe@wd}[1]{%
  \ifdim\wd#1<\minimum@arrow
    \minimum@arrow
  \else
    \wd#1%
  \fi
}
\newcommand{\minimum@arrow}{2.5em}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[
  A = \ker \left(A \xrightarrow{F} B \right)
  \qquad
  A = \ker \bigl(A \xrightarrow{F} B \bigr)
\]



\[
  A = \ker \left(
  \hspace{-\arraycolsep}
  \begin{tikzcd}
    A \arrow[r,"F"] & B
  \end{tikzcd}
  \hspace{-\arraycolsep}
  \right)
\]

\end{document}
```

I also added a trick to remove the padding to the `tikzcd` and also tried `\bigl(` and `\bigr)` to get a better output.

[image]

On the other hand, a simple `\ker(A\xrightarrow{F}B)` (with no patching) seems sufficient to me:

```latex
\[
  A = \ker \bigl(A \xrightarrow{F} B \bigr)
\]
```

produces

[image]